# The edge parity of the 4n vertex subgraphs of a 4n+1 vertex graph

Tags: graph-theory, parity

Is this true? If so why?
In EVERY 4n+1 vertex graph:
if EVERY vertex has an EVEN order then:
ALL the 4n+1 subgraphs of size 4n have either an odd number of edges or an even number of edges.

Comment: What's the big deal? EVERY graph has either an odd number of edges or an even number of edges.

Comment: @bof the user may or may not be asking in good faith: for example see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2688548/29335

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if in *any* finite graph $G$ all vertices $v$ have even degree $\deg v$ then the parity of number of edges $|E(G-v)|$ in each induced subgraph  $G-v$ is the same as the parity of number of edges $|E(G)|$ of the graph $G$, because $|E(G-v)|=|E(G)|-\deg v$.